# Sine function derivative

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am making a code for determining the derivative of a sine function, but I have two problems. And before you read them, please be aware that this is not my entire code (it's just the beginning. I didn't want to copy the whole code down because it is over 100 lines long), and it is nowhere near completed.

1. My code won't run. It always says syntax error and highlights the colon in the 'if' statement, which is weird because that part seems fine to me.
2. I don't want the spaces in between the calculated math values and printed strings when I print the solution. I added commas in between them, but I don't know how to get rid of the spaces that go there.

```
print("y=C(sin(Ax))^p")
C= float(input("What is the coefficient(C; c!=0)? "))
A= float(input("What is (A; A!=0)? "))
P= float(input("What is the function rasied to the power of (P; P!=0)?")
if P==1:
    if A==1:
        if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=cos(x)")
        elif C>0:
            print("dy/dx=",C,"cos(x)")
    elif A>1:
       if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=",A,"cos(",A,"x)")
        elif C>1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A,"x)")
        elif C<1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A,"x)")
    elif A<1:
        if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=",A,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
        elif C>1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
        elif C<1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
```

Comment: It would probably be shorter if you assembled the output string from its individual parts where for each part separately you replace `"1*"` and `"^0"` by the empty string whenever they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spacing was off.  Indentation is very important in python.  It's easiest to just tab over in python so you don't make mistakes like only hitting the space bar three times instead of four.  Look through the code below carefully, I corrected the spacing--the difference is subtle.

```
print("y=C(sin(Ax))^p")
C= float(input("What is the coefficient(C; c!=0)? "))
A= float(input("What is (A; A!=0)? "))
P= float(input("What is the function rasied to the power of (P; P!=0)?"))
if (P==1):
    if A==1:
        if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=cos(x)")
        elif C>0:
            print("dy/dx=",C,"cos(x)")
    elif A>1:
        if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=",A,"cos(",A,"x)")
        elif C>1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A,"x)")
        elif C<1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A,"x)")
    elif A<1:
        if C==1:
            print("dy/dx=",A,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
        elif C>1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
        elif C<1:
            print("dy/dx=",A*C,"cos(",A*-1,"x)")
```

As for printing without spacing, just use the `+` operator.  For example `print("some" + "thing")` would output the string `"something"`

Comment: I know I am supposed to refrain from commenting just to say thanks, but thank you very much. I really appreciate it.